# Setting uiimage to nil doesn't release memory with ARC

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uiimage, automatic-ref-counting

I have a scrollview that shows different images as it's scrolled through the pages, like PhotoScroller.  I'm using ARC.  When someone scrolls to another page, I set the image property of the UIImageView not being currently show to nil, as (attempting) to avoid memory crashes, which are still happening.  Then when the user scrolls to a new page, the image for that page is set as the UIImageView's image property, as well as the page before and after it (for smooth viewing).  The UIImage's for the pages are all held in an array.  Yet as I scroll through the pages, memory usage keeps going up, as if setting the UIImageView's `image` property to nil isn't releasing it from memory.  I use `initWithContentsOfFile` to initialize my UIImages.  I tried with `imageNamed` and `imageWithContentsOfFile` too, with no luck.  Here's my scrollview code:

`- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{

    int indexShown = self.scrollView.bounds.origin.x / kScrollObjWidth;`

```
for(NSNumber *index in indexesToRemove)
{
    UIImageView *imgViewToRemove = [[self.scrollView subviews] objectAtIndex:[index intValue]];
    imgViewToRemove.image = nil;
}
[indexesToRemove removeAllObjects];

UIImageView *imgViewToReplace = [[self.scrollView subviews] objectAtIndex:indexShown];
[imgViewToReplace setImage:[pageUIImagesArr objectAtIndex:indexShown]];
[indexesToRemove addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexShown]];

if(indexShown != 0 && ![[[self.scrollView subviews] objectAtIndex:indexShown-1] image])
{
    imgViewToReplace = [[self.scrollView subviews] objectAtIndex:indexShown-1];
    [imgViewToReplace setImage:[pageUIImagesArr objectAtIndex:indexShown-1]];
    [indexesToRemove addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexShown-1]];
}
if(indexShown != kNumImages-1 && ![[[self.scrollView subviews] objectAtIndex:indexShown+1] image])
{
    imgViewToReplace = [[self.scrollView subviews] objectAtIndex:indexShown+1];
    [imgViewToReplace setImage:[pageUIImagesArr objectAtIndex:indexShown+1]];
    [indexesToRemove addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexShown+1]];
}

currentView = [[self.scrollView subviews] objectAtIndex:indexShown];
//check which view is being shown`
```

Comment: What I discovered is that the way the images are created makes a huge difference.

Instead of 
    
    [UIImage imageNamed:xxxxx];

I used 

    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:imageFileNameTemp ofType:@"png"];
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

This saved my around 50% Live Bytes and #Living objects. I checked using the allocations Instrument. It puzzles me that you're not seeing better results when not using the static initialiser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The UIImage's for the pages are all held in an array.

The `UIImage`'s are not being deallocated when you set the `UIImageView`'s property to `nil` because the array is still holding a reference to them. As for the memory growth, it may be something else that is being allocated.  I'd suggest taking a look with Instrument's object allocation instrument to track down what exactly is growing as you scroll.

Comment: hmm.  but I load the uiimages into the array when the app launches.  i only set them as the uiimageview's image property, and then set it back to nil.  i figured if it was from being in the array, it would just crash at startup.  i did check the instruments, and memory usage grows by about 4 MB every time a new image that hasn't yet been shown is shown.

Comment: does it stop growing when the images that have already been shown are re-shown?

Comment: yeah, it only grows when they're originally loaded.  that's what's confusing me.

Comment: for anyone wondering, what i eventually did was replace the array of uiimages with an array of nsstrings that held the path of the image, and then loaded the images at the time i needed them, so that when i set them to nil after i was done with them, there was no reference being held to them.