# Apparent leaks: png_malloc

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, png, malloc

I have an application with various animations and images. The application runs just fine for about 30 minutes, but then crashes. I have looked through the instruments and I notice that there are a whole bunch of 7kB `png_malloc` allocations building each time I mark the heap (amounting to about 300kB every couple minutes).

I noticed in my leaks that every time an animation or `png` is used for the first time, there seems to be a "leak" of the data (although I am a bit skeptical whether this is a real leak or not).

All of these images have been declared using

```
frameName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"image.png"];
UIImage * u = [UIImage cachelessImageNamed:frameName];
```

so I don't believe there should be a problem with caching the images.

Has anyone else had the same problem with this `png_malloc` allocation?

[The instruments screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzYeV.jpg)

*Notes: I am using arc and the animations are getting set to `nil` in the deallocation function; however, these isn't called until the application exits. Does this create a problem each time the animation is run if it's only been created once?

**EDIT** Some more code:

```
-(void) createSymbolAnimations
{
    if (symbolAnimations == nil)
    {
        symbolAnimations = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }
    NSString * frameName;

    if (thisAnimation == nil)
    {
         thisAnimation = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    for (int x= 0; x< 40; x++)
    {
        frameName = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"image%d%s",x,".png"];
        UIImage * u = [UIImage cachelessImageNamed:frameName];
        [thisAnimation addObject:u];
    } 
    [symbolAnimations addObject:thisAnimation];
}
```

Is the creation of the animation. Imagine I have a few of these and then I change the animation set and start animating on touch with this snippet:

```
UIImageView * aView = [frameArray objectAtIndex:x];        
aView.image = [[symbolAnimations objectAtIndex:x]objectAtIndex:0];
[aView startAnimating];
```

Where `x` is the set of images I want to animate and `0` is the first frame of the animation.

So the image is changed quite a few times and I'm starting to worry that each time the animation images are changed, the RAM isn't cleared but instead over/rewritten.

**EDIT** Image grabber

```
+(UIImage *) cachelessImageNamed: (NSString *) name
{
    return [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:name ofType:nil]];
}
```

Comment: can you post more code? Not sure how frameName is being used.

Comment: Where does the implementation of cachelessImageNamed come from?

Comment: Oops, I forgot I wrote a function for that. Edited above.

Comment: When do you empty the arrays thisAnimation and symbolAnimations? At the moment you are only ever adding objects to them. I am guessing you want thisAnimation to be a local variable that you allocate every time you call createSymbolAnimations

Comment: createSymbolAnimations is only called at the loading of the application and then the arrays are emptied upon exiting the application. So ideally I shouldn't be using more memory every time I animate, but it seems to be for some reason.

Comment: Can you share the code for startAnimating?

Comment: I believe I found my problem. Answered by : [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977131/setting-uiimage-to-nil-doesnt-release-memory-with-arc)

Answer (score 4):

Just in case anyone stumbles upon this later, I found the problem.

The pngs used in this project for animations were created in Windows (not sure how pertinent that is) and it seems the file format is slightly different than the png that XCode is expecting. This disallows any png from being deallocated. If you convert the format to a png for Mac, it seems to work fine. I did this through

```
 mogrify -type truecolormatte -format png *.png
```

After adjusting all of my images, the leaks were *greatly* reduced and everything seems to run fine.