# set UIImage:nil in scrollview doesn't release memory with ARC if already referenced outside of scrollview

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, uiscrollview, uiimage, automatic-ref-counting

Here's what my app does.

1. It requests about 100 images from the server when it starts up. It stores
   those images in model objects, we'll call them `modelObject.storedImage`
2. The `modelObject` also has a `viewObject`, which is a `UIImageView` subclass
3. The app has a 2D scrollview that sets all 100 `viewObject`s as subviews, with up to 16 of those shown in the scrollview content area at any give time
4. When you scroll to a given area, it finds the 16 images from the appropriate
   `modelObject.storedImage` and does

   ```
   modelObject.viewObject.image = modelObjects.storedImage;
   ```
5. When a viewObject scrolls out of the content area, it is purged from the view

   ```
   [modelObject.viewObject setImage:nil]; 
   [modelObject.viewObject removeFromSuperview];
   ```

The problem is, despite the purging, memory keeps growing as you scroll to new areas of the scrollview content area.  Memory from putting the former `modelObject.viewObject.image`s on the scrollview is not released.  So if you scroll to enough new areas, memory use gets out of control.

To be clear, when the app first loads the 100 images into the `modelObject.storedImage`s, memory does not get out of control.  Furthermore, if I comment this out

```
//modelObject.viewObject.image = modelObjects.storedImage;
```

then memory also stays fine (but of course the scrollviews subviews don't show any image).

I did see this question "[Setting uiimage to nil doesn't release memory with ARC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7977131/setting-uiimage-to-nil-doesnt-release-memory-with-arc)" but I believe it's different because in my app I can't afford to keep requesting images over and over from the server.  They must sit at `modelObject.storedImage` once they've been requested, always ready to be displayed when their corresponding `viewObject` is scrolled to.

Surely there must be a way to tell ARC to release the memory for these nil images?  Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

1. If images are created by `imageNamed:`, then no way to manually to release memory, you can optimize it by `imageWithContentsOfFile`, thanks to you are using images for server, I think you used `imageWithContentsOfFile`. :)
2. You can try use `@autoreleasepool {}` at scrolling method to release memory in real time.
3. You can try release viewObject instead of removeFromSuperview, maybe what you should store is viewFrame rather than viewObject.

Hope offer you some help.

Comment: Thanks so much for the ideas.  Here's the three results: 1. I actually don't create the image, it's supplied by AFNetworking as a UIImage in imageRequestOperationWithRequest:imageProcessingBlock:success:failure:2. Tried adding @autoreleasepool {} in a few places, it has no affect 3. If I do `[modelObject.viewObject release];' I get the error "ARC forbids release". 
:/

Comment: to release viewObject, in ARC, you should do like this: modelObject.viewObject = nil;

Comment: Thx @simalone. Bummer though, I tried modelObject.viewObject = nil; in the purge, and when it scrolls back to that area recreating the viewObject like this modelObject.viewObject = [[viewObject alloc] init];, but memory still grows the same as before.  Strangely, even if I don't recreate the viewObject and just let it be purged forever, memory still grows the same.  There is some problem w/ setting an image on a scrollview and then having completely unrelated references already pointing to it that leaks memory, as I hope I described in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

So I went around this problem and did this as a solution.  I'd be curious to see if someone has a more robust idea.  I made a copy of the image and set the copy on the scrollview. Now when I purge that copy, its memory is actually released (thank you!!), while the original image still sits comfortably in the model.  Note, it did not work to simply copy the image's CGImage and make a copy off that, in which case memory did not release.  I had to make a new copy using a `UIGraphicsImageContext`.

Code to set the image on Scrollview:

```
    UIImage *imageToCopy = modelObject.imageStore;
    CGSize size = imageToCopy.size;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
    [imageToCopy drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, imageToCopy.size.width, imageToCopy.size.height)];
    UIImage *copiedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    [modelObject.viewObject setImage:copiedImage];
```

Code to purge when it's off the scrollview's content area:

```
    [modelObject.viewObject setImage:nil];
    [modelObject.viewObject removeFromSuperview];
```

The only problem was that drawing those image contexts used a lot of memory, so I added this modification to make the drawing smaller:

```
    ...
    CGSize size = imageToCopy.size;
    size.width *= .2;
    size.height *= .2;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);
    [imageToCopy drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, imageToCopy.size.width*.2, imageToCopy.size.height*.2)];
    ...
```